# Whats the equivalent asp.net/c# code for this php code?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

```
<?php

$system = $_POST['system']; // The FreshBooks system
$name = $_POST['name']; // The name of the event that just happened, e.g.invoice.create
$id = $_POST['object_id'];

$subject = "[$system] Event: $name";

if ($name=='callback.verify') {
$body = "
$name just happened on $system

Verification token: ".$_POST['verifier']."
";

} else {
$body = "
$name just happened
on $system
for id: $id
";
}

mail('youraddress@example.com',$subject,$body);

?>
```

Comment: For C# developers who don't know PHP: this code receives data from a POST form and sends an e-mail message with it. You're welcome.

Comment: I thought that was obvious. (And I don't know PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have a standard ASPX page listening for people to post to it. (You could also use a ASHX handler but I won't get into that)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/C#" runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var systemValue = Request.Form["system"];
            var nameValue = Request.Form["name"];
            var idValue = Request.Form["object_id"];
            var verifierValue = Request.Form["verifier"];

            var subject = string.Format("{0} Event: {1}", systemValue, nameValue);
            string body;

            if ( nameValue.Equals("callback verify", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
                    body = string.Format("\n{0} just happened on {1}\n\nVerification token: {2}\n", nameValue, systemValue, verifierValue );
            else
                    body = string.Format("\n{0} just happened on {1} for id: {2}\n", nameValue, systemValue, idValue);

            var email = new MailMessage(
                    new MailAddress( "fromserver@anywhere.com")
                    , new MailAddress( "youraddress@anywhere.com") )
                            {
                                Subject = subject, Body = body
                            };

            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            smtpServer.Send( email );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, somewhere else, presumably in your postbin.org page, you need an HTML page that posts to another. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Default.aspx" method="post">  
        <input type="text" id="system" name="system" />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <input type="text" id="object_id" name="object_id" />
        <input type="text" id="verifier" name="verifier" />

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this standard Html page, I'm setting the form action to post to my ASPX page. When that happens, the Page_Load event on the ASPX page will fire and send the email (assuming the email settings are configured in the ASPX page's web.config file).

Comment: How would I put this into a web or windows service to read from postbin.org for example?

Comment: This could be done via a code-behind page on a basic ASP.NET page or done via a handler page.

Comment: ok in my code behind, how would i tell it that i want it to read request from postbin.org

Comment: You would post *to* the page that contains the above code-behind from somewhere else. When that happens, the above code will read the post via Request.Form.

Comment: Expanding a bit, your postbin.org needs to post to an ASP.NET aspx page that contains the above code in say its Page_Load event.

Comment: I kind of understand that, but I am not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Updated my post to better explain.

Comment: Ok that is a better explanation, so basically I need postbin.org to post to my aspx page, I can just read directly from postbin.org

Comment: Correct. Said another way, you can read from anything that posts to the aspx page including postbin.org.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class and the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) object.

Answer (score 0):

To get the request values you would do something like this

```
string myValue = Request.Form["MyPostArgument"];
```

You can then use the string.format class to setup the messages

```
string subject = string.format("{0} Event: {1}", mySystem, myEvent);
```

You then need to use the SmtpClient and MailMessage objects to build out the e-mail.